# how to change content type from Document set to Item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type

While creating content type I've selected Item as a parent but after created I can see its showing Document Set as a parent content type. Now can anyone please suggest if possible I can change the parent content type from Document Set to Item.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might not have selected **Parent Content Type Source** properly, Do select Parent content Source and then select Item from the list.